# https always redirect to the same domain

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I already have a domain setup using SSL / https .
It all works fine.

Now I setup a second domain, in http all works fine.
But in https it redirect to the first domain not the new one.

Any idea what I am missing?

Comment: If you could add more details and information, it may be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Sorry I realized I did not even specify the server:  I am using ubuntu apache 2.   I should note the 1st domain was not setup by me, so I dont know all the details.  But I double checked the sites-avaiable settings, and 000-default.conf .

Comment: May be the question is more where would be the setting to redirect all https request to one domain

Comment: problem solved. Configuration was fine for some reason something was cached on the browser.